# Can't use hotkeys for vertex/edge/face selection

Tags: customization, versions

I just downloaded the latest daily build "blender-2.80-532536bf52da-win64" and when I launch it and try to use those hotkeys, they don't work nor show in the keymap preferences.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

go to preferences>keymaps>3D View>Mesh>Mesh(Global) at the bottom click 'add new' in the new key map paste `mesh.select_mode` and configure the keymap how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this helped.